# Check logical value inside a string in python

Tags: python

I mean I have this string var:

```
mystr1 = "1==1 or 1==2"
mystr2 = "1==1 and 1==2"
if_logical_string(mystr1) must be True
if_logical_string(mystr2) must be False
```

How can I achieve this? Is there any lib to do so ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use python's [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) function.

However, I would recommend having another approach... There's *always*  another solution...

Answer (score 2):

```
mystr1 = "1==1 or 1==2"
mystr2 = "1==1 and 1==2"

# will output True
print(eval(mystr1))

# will output False
print(eval(mystr2))
```

If you have a mathematical expression, there is a more elegant way using Pyparsing. Check out this post: [from Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371436/evaluating-a-mathematical-expression-in-a-string)